# Check if intent is calling or Activity is started by default

Tags: android, android-intent, methods

how can I check if Activity is started by default or a method of the Activity is called from an intent in an other activity?
I think at the moment my Code is very bad, because i handle it over a Try/Catch
It works fine, but i want better code

```
public class MyScan extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = ".MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkIntent();
}

public void checkIntent() {
    try {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String method_name = i.getStringExtra("method_name");// is firing an error if there is no intent call
        if (method_name.equals("scanBarcode")) {
            scanBarcode2();// That starts my method
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_scan); // that shows just my Content
    }

}
....
```

Thanky you for your hint Alex Terreaux

i changed the code this way

```
public void checkIntent() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i != null) {
        String method_name = i.getStringExtra("method_name");
        if (method_name != null && method_name.equals("scanBarcode")) {
            scanBarcode2();
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_scan);
        }
    }
}
```

and that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking if the result of `getIntent()` is null.

Comment: You mean like     if (i != null)

Comment: closed but not cigar, because
   if (i != null) is true but you put me in the right direction, see in my originally post

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 4):

You could use extras. In strings.xml add a new string:

```
<string name="starting_from_intent">STARTING_FROM_INTENT</string>
```

In the file where you are starting the activity by intent you can use:

```
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.starting_from_intent), 1);
```

Then, in the checkIntent(), do:

```
boolean startedFromIntent;

Intent i = getIntent();
if (i.getIntExtra(getString(R.string.starting_from_intent), 0) == null
|| i.getIntExtra(getString(R.string.starting_from_intent), 0) == 0) 
    startedFromIntent = false;

else 
    startedFromIntent = true;
```

Hope this wasn't too hard to understand and hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry - I accidentally posted two answers. I hope this one is more detailed. I didn't mean to post the other answer...

Answer (score 0):

When your activity was started just by startActivity() a getCallingActivity() method in target activity will return null.

When it was called by startActivityForResult() it will return name of calling activity.